# Insert and automatically play audio files in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, audio, office365, ms-office, powerpoint

I have this code (credit to Shyam Pillai):

```
Sub SampleTest()
Call InsertAudio("G:\Music\track1.mp3", ActivePresentation.Slides(1))
Call InsertAudio("G:\Music\track2.mp3", ActivePresentation.Slides(2))

End Sub

Sub InsertAudio(Track As String, oSlide As Slide)
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oEffect As Effect

'Add the audio shape
Set oShp = oSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(Track, True, False, 10, 10)

'Set audio to play automatically
Set oEffect = oSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(oShp, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
oEffect.MoveTo 1

'Hide during slide show
With oEffect
    .EffectInformation.PlaySettings.HideWhileNotPlaying = True
End With

End Sub
```

The code works but I would like to know what can I add to it so when I run the code it opens a dialog box where I can insert an audio list from a file, which would be then inserted one by one, slide by slide with the settings in the code (automatic, hide during show).

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you say 'it doesn't work' please be more specific. What happens, what have you tried? Here are some guidelines about how to ask a question on this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This code works just fine for me in 2016 if the path is correct and there is an appropriate file to process. Make sure you actually have a file called `G:\Music\track1.mp3` and that it contains all of the codecs.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It does work so I will update the question with what I want to achieve with the code, which is getting a dialog box where I can input an audio list, which would be then inserted into the presentation, slide by slide, with settings specified in the code

Comment: Assuming a Windows version of PowerPoint, look up VBA help for FileDialog. You can use the FileDialog object to return a user-selected list of files. There's a decent explanation with useful examples here:  https://analystcave.com/vba-application-filedialog-select-file/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, instead of adding mp3 files manually, you can add an  m3u file and play a sequence of mp3 files.
An M3U format file just goes like this:

```
G:\Music\track1.mp3
G:\Music\track2.mp3
track3.mp3
```

Here, you can omit the detailed path if the mp3 file is located in the same folder as the m3u file. So you can add an m3u file using VBA or manually just like you can add an mp3 file. The only disadvantages are that you can't embed the mp3 files in your pptx file and that you can't put an mp3 file in a specific slide.